# Stop Firefox from asking users if they want to "Refresh" their profile

Tags: firefox, passwords, refresh

Firefox occasionally suggests that a "Refresh" might improve performance.  We had a naive user press that button and wipe out a significant amount of customisation. Part of what resulted is that the master password option was turned on by the refresh, even though the user had not set a master password and had never enabled that feature. Of course, there being no master password it was impossible to turn the master password option off.  We fixed this by running the password reset thing: `chrome://pippki/content/resetpassword.xhtml` but researching this was a considerable time waster.

We also had to reinstall their addons along with all the company PKI certificates.  Their previous profile being saved to their desktop notwithstanding.

These sort of user bombs are about as unfriendly a UI as I can imagine.

In any case, how does one turn off that particular annoyance so that the unwary are not led to do something they really, really would not chose to do if they knew what it did.

Comment: Misleading, stupid and unprofessional feature. "Welcome back!" -- they think that we mustn't have used the computer for a long time just because we haven't lanuched firefox for a long time. Where does this misplaced air of self-importance come from in apps? It's everywhere; "It can't matter that much if we just send you *one* notification that you haven't asked for, because surely you don't have *other* apps on your phone doing the same thing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yap the old "refresh" setting from Firefox. I find it super misleading that it wipes out [many](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) settings. Similar to the unimposing "format" term to clear storage mediums.

From a quick search, the below setting appears to be what you are looking for.

```
about:config
browser.meta_refresh_when_inactive.disabled = true
```

The default behavior seems to be that if Firefox has been inactive for 60 days, the popup appears. The above setting should prevent that.

Comment: I think that may be it.  But given the way the setting is worded one would be hard pressed to decide which setting (T/F)  did what.  Why could it not just say "browser.meta_refresh_when_inactive (T/F) and have T as the default?  It seems as if the mozilla team goes out of their way to be obscure.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but that is not an uncommon thing. Basically false means default behavior. While true means customized. Windows policies for example have similar wordings. Or are you saying it was true on your system?

Comment: No, it was false.  It will take some time to see if it works however, unless I can find the reporting interval switch. In any case,  I was not aware of the false vs. true convention respecting flagging default behaviour.

Comment: On the other hand, when I look at about:config I see that many of the default values are true.